# Coldfusion 11 and Lucee Server on Same Machine

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have Installed `Lucee` and `Coldfusion` 11 on Same Machines, Both works fine but there is a catch.

I don't remember how many tomcat versions i installed because ColdFusion has its own, lucee has its own, `ColdFusion` runs on Port `8501`, while `lucee` runs on Port `8888`

But to make run both, i am not able to do it, I have to shutdown lucee to run ColdFusion and vice versa.

I forgot how i managed to find the error, but it was something related to the

> shutdown port which 8009

i suppose

How can i fix this

Comment: Your question is kind of ambiguous... What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Better suited to ServerFault

Answer (score 3):

You can change the ports that Tomcat listens to in your Lucee installation by modifying your tomcat server.xml file, located here by default:

C:\lucee\tomcat\conf\server.xml

The specific configurations you'll be looking for are:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

and

```
<Connector port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

and

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: so should i change all ports or just 1 to make sure both ACF and lucee works

Answer (score 1):

You can run both (since they are on different ports) -- it is just a matter of configuring your connector on the front-end web server to proxy connections to whichever one you want. On Windows you can configure Boncode AJP on a per-site basis, and it's better than ACF's default ISAPI connectors anyway.

Sounds like you're not on Windows, so you would set up mod_proxy or mod_jk to do this instead.

If you're just asking 'how do I shut down Coldfusion,' then there are shutdown scripts for Tomcat with both ACF and Lucee in the directories where you installed them.

Comment: I am on Windows, I want to run both but due to its conflicting issues i have to stop to make another work